# Is there a faster way to calculate the distance between elements in the same matrix with a Gaussian function?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, distance, gaussian

Starting from an M matrix of shape 7000 x 2, I calculate the following quantity:
[image]

I do it in the following way (the variance sigma is arbitrary):

```
W = np.zeros((M.shape[0], M.shape[0]))
elements_sum_by_i = np.zeros((M.shape[0]))
for i in range (0,M.shape[0]):
    #normalization
    for k in range (0, M.shape[0]):
        elements_sum_by_i[k] = math.exp(-(np.linalg.norm(M[i,:] - M[k,:])**2)/(2*sigma**2))
    sum_by_i = sum(elements_sum_by_i)
    #calculation
    for j in range (0,M.shape[0]):
        W[i,j] = (math.exp(-(np.linalg.norm(M[i,:] - M[j,:]))**2/(2*sigma**2)))/(sum_by_i)
```

The problem is that it is really very slow (takes about 30 minutes). Is there a faster way to do this calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can extract some ideas from the following comments:

1) Calculate the Log(W[i,j]) with the simplifications of the formula, the exponents disappear, the processing should be quicker.

2) Take the exponent of it: Exp(Log(W{i,j])) == W[i,j]

3) Use variables for values that are constants inside the iterations like sigma = 2*sigma**2, that you can compute at start outside of the iterations.

Important, before any change, memorize the result so that your new development can be tested on the final matrix result that you already know, I suppose, is correct.

Good luck.